# Migrating subscriptions from one Stripe account to another

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

We want to migrate Stripe customers, products, and subscriptions from one account to another. The thing is that one of the accounts has recently become suspended and we can't take charges from the customers via this account. The second one is fine and fully active. We want to transfer the data and continue taking charges from clients with active subscriptions. Can we do it or is it against Stripe policy?

We haven’t found any information about migrating subscribers from a suspended account.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t copy individual charges, invoices, plans and subscriptions, coupons, events, and logs from one stripe Account to another. You can only copy the raw customers objects. [This process is a copy](https://support.stripe.com/questions/copy-existing-account-data-to-a-new-stripe-account), not a migration, so all of your old data will remain in your old account. We recommend keeping the original “old” account around so you can access the legacy data there if you ever need to reference it.
You can follow this [Stripe Support Article](https://support.stripe.com/questions/recreate-subscriptions-and-plans-after-moving-customer-data-to-a-new-stripe-account) about how you recreate subscriptions in your second account.